# Create "continue" arrow button in iOS8

Tags: ios

Is it possible in iOS8 to create a "right" / "continue" arrow button (not a `UINavigationItem`). For example in native maps app, the little gray arrow next to selected annotation.

[image: iOS maps annotation button arrow]

I don't want to use button with ">" character either, it looks different and seems wrong.

Edit: Looking for something like

```
UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure)
```

but .DetailDisclosure was changed in iOS7 to look like (i) .

Comment: You could use an imageview to replace the default view of a button.

Answer (score 2):

That button on `MKAnnotationView` is the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` as a button set to button type `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`.

You should be able to use that same type for a normal button...

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Comment: @Formeister : In iOS8 (or possibly iOS7 from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Controls.html ) the .DetailDisclosure is shown as (i) .

Comment: Hmm... I took that from the MKAnnotationView documentation. Not sure then. Unless you can create the image yourself.

Comment: @Savannah maybe you can also use a button with an unicode title.. this is a list with unicode codes http://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use/